# Display text middle in span

Tags: css

I want to my text which is SUN, MON to be display `vertical-align:middle;` but still no luck. Currently the text is at the top left side. What is the problem with my coding? How can I correct this?

```
<td colspan="2">
    <span id="selectable">
        <span style="width:35px;height:35px;display:inline-block;" class="ui-widget-content">SUN</span>
        <span style="width:35px;height:35px;display:inline-block;" class="ui-widget-content">MON</span>
    </span>
</td>
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For text to be vertically aligned within `<span>` you need to set `line-height` instead of `height`:

```
line-height: 35px;
```

`vertical-align:middle;` works for text inside `table-cell` elements. It also affects vertical positioning of `inline-block` elements, but not text nodes.

You can find a good explanation of this here: http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/

and more information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Comment: In this case, you can just use `line-height` *instead of* `height`. No need to duplicate...

Comment: Yes you are right, in this case `height` rule is redundant. I'll update answer.

Comment: I would give you an *additional* +1 after your update, but that's not possible... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, `line-height` doesn't work if your text wraps onto two lines, use instead on your `<td>` element:

```
vertical-align:middle; text-align:center;
```